# Android Apps will not stop updating, no matter what I try

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I've searched extensively on this and I see many threads where the advice relates to drilling into the apps individual menu list and 'un-checking' the 'Enable auto-update' box.

Anyway, I'm at my wits end here now.  For whatever reason, I do not want ANY apps to update by themselves.  This functionality has been well supported in Android for a long time now and has worked.  However, it no longer does and it's extremely frustrating - I'm turning to the collective brain here to see if anyone is able to help me at all?

Here are the details:

Galaxy Note9 (SM-N960F UK)
Vodafone contract (UK)
Android 8.1.0
Sams Exper Version 9.5

1. Google playstore : Auto updates is turned OFF
2. Samsung Galaxy Apps: Auto update apps, is turned OFF
3. **Every SINGLE app in the Play store list has been checked that the 'Enable auto-update' is NOT checked.** (this is the one that everyone seems to immediately advise upon, however I have covered this off already)

And yet, at least 40-odd apps have recently auto-updated and continue to do so!

It's driving me nuts.

Is anyone else having the same experience and - is anyone able to assist at all please?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your phone have an alternative market app? Some manufacturers add their own market app to install and update apps. Also, when they get updated, did you confirm that it was the Google Play which updated them?

Comment: Current apps installed/updated via Playstore contain a special signature. Therefore it should be possible to check if an updated app was installed by Google Playstore or a 3rd party market. Additionally check the special app permissions for apps which can install other apps?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - interesting points.   I was aware that the Samsung Galaxy app also was able to update apps, but assumed it was restricted to only apps that originated from there.   But as far as I am aware, outside of the Play store and the Galaxy store, I can't think of another app that would a: have permission to update such a (seemingly) random array of apps and b: would even want to.   You mention there is a way to tell via the 'signature' which app has updated another app - I am not aware of how to do this, could you elaborate please?  Many thanks, Ash.